# Android Seperate onactivityresult() implementations for activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I am using onactivityresult() in my parent activity and it works fine. However, I would also like a seperate onactivityresult() implementation for my fragment which allows user to select an image from gallery and then set it to image view. This is my fragment code :

```
Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                choosePictureIntent.setType("image/*");
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, PICK_PICTURE);
```

and then

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {

            if(requestCode == PICK_PICTURE)
            {
                if(data==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Try picking a file again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    pictureUri = data.getData();
                    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureUri.toString()).into(img);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ffdc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the toast displaying 'FFDC' never gets called nor does the image get set from picasso. So I think the onactivityresult itself isnt getting called. How do I fix this ?
I found a number of similar questions but none of them seemed to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: i am also facing exactly same issue. please suggest !!